# Default locale in console commands is always en_us rather than the site default

Tags: plugin-development

The default (and only) locale for my site is `en`, however, when trying to query the `ElementService` from a console command without specifying the locale in the criteria, the locale used in the query is `en_us`. As such, the query returns no results. For example:

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

class ShoppingCommand extends BaseCommand {

    public function actionListOrders() {
        $c = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
        $c->section = 'orders';
        $c->limit = 5;
        foreach($c as $o) {
            print $o->id . ": " . $o->title . "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

prints nothing, even though there are entries present for the default locale `en`.

Printing out the query object `print_r(craft()->elements->buildElementsQuery($c));` shows the `:locale` parameter being passed to the sql query as `en_us`. But this locale doesn't even exist for the site (`select * from craft_locales` shows only `en`).

The only way I could find to work around this is by adding the site's default locale to the criteria manually with:

```
$c->locale = craft()->i18n->getPrimarySiteLocale();
```

However, since the query works find without this when run in a controller, I'm skeptical that it should be needed. Is this is a bug, or is there some extra configuration i'm missing? Having some parameter to specify the locale to use for commands would make sense in mutli-locale environments, but I would still expect the default to be the site's default rather than `en_us`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is actually a bug, too.

It's going to end up being more involved to fix than a build release probably warrants, though, so it'll have to wait for the upcoming 2.3 release to get a proper fix.

In the meantime, you'll be able to get by with your workaround of manually setting it.

```
$c->locale = craft()->i18n->getPrimarySiteLocale();
```